# Distribute android app release version without certificate

Tags: android, react-native

Not going to distribute the app just want to release a react-native app for testing without `debugging mode`.

I use this `./gradlew assembleRelease` to compile a release version.

When I try to install it `adb install app-release-unsigned.apk`, it give me this error:

```
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]
```

What is the error?

Can I distribute it without signing?

Comment: you can, check my answer but the installations will require developer mode since you are installing from apk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Android will only install signed APKs.  Even debug versions are signed, they're signed with a debug key Android Studio creates when its run the first time.  You don't have to sign it with your release key though if you don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

Transfer the apk to a device and you can use an app called apk-signer from the play store, this app will provide a signature to the apk and then you can install it or distribute it